# Prove that a curve in 2D is the result of looking at another 2D curve in 3D space.

Tags: 3d, curves, plane-curves

Consider the graphs of $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$:
[image]

It seems to me that $g(x)$ looks like it is $f(x)$ looked at from a specific angle in 3D, where $V$ is some vector perpendicular to the $x,y$ plane:
[image]

Is there any way to prove whether this is the case, or whether, actually, it is impossible for it to be the case?

I'd be interested in any resources I could use to learn about such relationships. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise we need an explicit model of what "projection" means. One natural definition is perspective projection, which it sounds as if you have in mind: Pick an arbitrary plane $P$ and a point $O$ not on $P$, and imagine a light source at $O$ casting shadows on $P$. (In more detail, map each point $x \neq O$ to the intersection of the line $\overline{Ox}$ with $P$. We can either tolerate that this mapping is undefined where $\overline{Ox}$ is parallel to $P$, or we can work in "projective space" where "parallel lines meet at infinity" in a precise sense.)

In this model, a parabola is a conic (algebraically a curve of degree two, geometrically the intersection of a right circular cone and a plane), so it not equivalent to the graph of $g$, which is not a conic.

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know if this pertains to a specific area of mathematics? Is this what is referred to as projective geometry? I'd like to find out how "parallel lines meet at infinity" is defined.

Comment: You're very welcome. Yes, "projective geometry" is a good search term. There are "topological" pictures of the real projective plane, but for your purposes it's probably better to think of a "point" in the projective plane as a line through the origin in Cartesian three-space, and a "line" in the projective plane as a plane through the origin. Note that any two distinct projective lines intersect in a point. Incidentally, "at infinity" makes sense only with respect to a particular "affine plane" (a plane in three-space not passing through the origin).